# Why don't SCOM R2 web console performance views load?

Tags: iis-7.5, scom

When I select any performance view via my SCOM R2 web console, I get the following error:

> Unexpected error
>   There was an error displaying the page you requested.

... and some suggestions about restarting my browser, which doesn't resolve the issue.

The request produces the following event in the logs:

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 7/05/2010 11:41:38 AM 
>   Event time (UTC): 7/05/2010 1:41:38 AM
>   Event ID: f4c47d1302694e1c8039e6c0088c2520 
>   Event sequence: 18  
>   Event occurrence:1
>   Event detail code: 0
>   
>   [snip]
>   
>   Exception information: 
>   Exception type: HttpException 
>   Exception message: Error executing child request for /ResultViews/ViewTypePerformance.aspx.

I'm using forms authentication and all other web console functionality works perfectly.

My server is Windows 2008 R2 Standard running SCOM R2 and runs the DB, Web Console and RMS roles.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Is it fixed in the cumulative update release for SCOM R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has to do with permissions on your Web Console directory.  Whatever the Identity of the OpWebConsoleApp app pool is running as (I've changed mine to Network Service), be sure to add that to the Web Console directory and give it at Full Control (Modify may work too, but Read is not enough).  Also, to avoid JScript errors be sure Authenticated Users and the machine name of the RMS/web console from AD is added with Read access as well (example SCOMRMS$).

Note: the web console role must be installed on the RMS if using Windows Auth.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735415.aspx

Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks very much, this was doing my head in.